# Lazy sequence using loop/recur?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to write an implementation to an algorithm that produces an infinite sequence of results, where each element represents the calculation of a single iteration of the algorithm. Using a lazy sequence is convenient, as it decouples the logic of the number of iterations (by using `take`) and *burn-in* iterations (by using `drop`) from the implementation.

Here's an example of two algorithm implementations, one that produces a lazy sequence (`yadda-lazy`), and one that does not (`yadda-loop`).

```
(defn yadda-iter
  [v1 v2 v3]

  (+ (first v1)
     (first v2)
     (first v3)))

(defn yadda-lazy
  [len]

  (letfn [(inner [v1 v2 v3]
            (cons (yadda-iter v1 v2 v3)
                  (lazy-seq (inner (rest v1)
                                   (rest v2)
                                   (rest v3)))))]
    (let [base (cycle (range len))]
      (inner base
             (map #(* %1 %1) base)
             (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base)))))

(defn yadda-loop
  [len iters]

  (let [base (cycle (range len))]
    (loop [result nil
           i 0
           v1 base
           v2 (map #(* %1 %1) base)
           v3 (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base)]
      (if (= i iters)
        result
        (recur (cons (yadda-iter v1 v2 v3) result)
               (inc i)
               (rest v1)
               (rest v2)
               (rest v3))))))

(prn (take 11 (yadda-lazy 4)))
(prn (yadda-loop 4 11))
```

Is there a way to create a lazy sequence using the same style as `loop`/`recur`? I like `yadda-loop` better, because:

- It's more obvious what the initial conditions are and how the algorithm progresses to the next iteration.
- It won't suffer from a stack overflow due to tail optimization.

Comment: Lazy sequences won't overflow the stack anyway. In order to overflow the stack, you need to keep building up stack frames, whereas a lazy sequence just returns a sequence with the current item in the head and a thunk for the tail. In other words, the  first call to `inner` will return before the next call occurs, so the stack stays at a constant depth.

Comment: You won't get a stack overflow error, but you can get an `OutOfMemoryError` if you hang onto the head (you'll overflow the memory, not the stack).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your loop version would be better written to (1) pull the addition out of the loop so you don't have to recur on so many sequences, and (2) use `conj` on a vector accumulator so your results are in the same order as your `yadda-lazy`.

```
(defn yadda-loop-2 [len iters]
  (let [v1 (cycle (range len))
        v2 (map * v1 v1)
        v3 (map * v1 v2)
         s (map + v1 v2 v3)]
    (loop [result [], s s, i 0]
      (if (= i iters)
        result
        (recur (conj result (first s)), (rest s), (inc i))))))
```

However, at this point it becomes clear that the loop is pointless as this is just

```
(defn yadda-loop-3 [len iters]
   (let [v1 (cycle (range len))
         v2 (map * v1 v1)
         v3 (map * v1 v2)
         s (map + v1 v2 v3)]
     (into [] (take iters s))))
```

and we might as well pull out the `iters` parameter, return simply `s` and `take` from it.

```
(defn yadda-yadda [len]
   (let [v1 (cycle (range len))
         v2 (map * v1 v1)
         v3 (map * v1 v2)]
     (map + v1 v2 v3)))
```

This produces the same results as your `yadda-lazy`, is also lazy, and is quite clear

```
(take 11 (yadda-yadda 4)) ;=> (0 3 14 39 0 3 14 39 0 3 14)
```

You could also, equivalently

```
(defn yadda-yadda [len] 
  (as-> (range len) s 
        (cycle s)
        (take 3 (iterate (partial map * s) s))
        (apply map + s)))
```

**Addendum**

If you are looking for a pattern for converting an eager loop like yours to a lazy-sequence

1. `(loop [acc [] args args] ...)` -> `((fn step [args] ...) args)`
2. `(if condition (recur ...) acc)` -> `(when condition (lazy-seq ...)`
3. `(recur (conj acc (f ...)) ...)` -> `(lazy-seq (cons (f ...) (step ...)))`

Applying this to your `yadda-lazy`

```
(defn yadda-lazy-2 [len iters]
  (let [base (cycle (range len))]
    ((fn step [i, v1, v2, v3]
      (when (< i iters)
        (lazy-seq 
          (cons (yadda-iter v1 v2 v3)
            (step (inc i), (rest v1), (rest v2), (rest v3))))))
      0, base, (map #(* %1 %1) base), (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base))))
```

And at this point you'd probably want to pull out the `iters`

```
(defn yadda-lazy-3 [len]
  (let [base (cycle (range len))]
    ((fn step [v1, v2, v3]
        (lazy-seq 
          (cons (yadda-iter v1 v2 v3)
            (step (rest v1), (rest v2), (rest v3)))))
      base, (map #(* %1 %1) base), (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base))))
```

So you can

```
(take 11 (yadda-lazy-3 4)) ;=> (0 3 14 39 0 3 14 39 0 3 14)
```

And then you might say, hey, my `yadda-iter` is just applying `+` on the first and `step` is applied on the rest, so why not combine my `v1, v2, v3` and make this a bit clearer?

```
(defn yadda-lazy-4 [len]
  (let [base (cycle (range len))]
    ((fn step [vs]
        (lazy-seq 
          (cons (apply + (map first vs))
            (step (map rest vs)))))
      [base, (map #(* %1 %1) base), (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base)])))
```

And lo and behold, you have just re-implemented variadic map

```
(defn yadda-lazy-5 [len]
  (let [base (cycle (range len))]
    (map + base, (map #(* %1 %1) base), (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base))))
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. But your code inspired me to re-code the implementation using `iterate` and `map` instead of using `lazy-seq` and `cons`. Part of the problem was that I was co-recurring over several items (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`), and it wasn't immediately obvious how to do so with `iterate`, since `iterate` only allows one element. That was solved by wrapping all co-recurring elements in a vector and deconstructing it to get the individual co-recurring elements back from the vector.

Comment: @SamadLotia I'm not sure I understood your question then, but see the addendum I just edited in.

Answer (score 5):

@A.Webb's answer is perfect, but if your love for `loop`/`recur` overcomes his arguments, know that you can still combine both styles of recursion.

For example, take a look at the implementation of `range`:

```
(defn range
  (...)
  ([start end step]
   (lazy-seq
    (let [b (chunk-buffer 32)
          comp (cond (or (zero? step) (= start end)) not=
                     (pos? step) <
                     (neg? step) >)]
      (loop [i start]                        ;; chunk building through loop/recur
        (if (and (< (count b) 32)
                 (comp i end))
          (do
            (chunk-append b i)
            (recur (+ i step)))
          (chunk-cons (chunk b) 
                      (when (comp i end) 
                        (range i end step))))))))) ;; lazy recursive call
```

Here's another example, an alternate implementation of `filter`:

```
(defn filter [pred coll]
  (letfn [(step [pred coll]
            (when-let [[x & more] (seq coll)]
              (if (pred x)
                (cons x (lazy-seq (step pred more))) ;; lazy recursive call
                (recur pred more))))]                ;; eager recursive call
    (lazy-seq (step pred coll))))
```

Comment: I did look at the code for `range` and `filter`. Indeed, my solution for a lazy sequence (`yadda-lazy`) follows the form of `filter`, which is precisely what I was trying to avoid. `range` just looks way too complicated to replicate.

Comment: I agree, `range` is a mouthful. But I don't understand why you prefer the `loop`/`recur` style. From the issues you mentioned, the stack overflow risk has been addressed ; and I don't see how the initial conditions are more obvious - is it that they are introduced first ?

Answer (score 0):

[The Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) has a new `lazy-gen`/`yield` feature that mimics `generator functions` in Python.  It can generate a lazy sequence from any point in a looping structure. Here is version of `yadda-loop` that shows `lazy-gen` & `yield` in action:

```
(ns tst.xyz
  (:use clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(defn yadda-lazy-gen
  [len iters]
  (t/lazy-gen
    (let [base (cycle (range len))]
      (loop [i      0
             v1     base
             v2     (map #(* %1 %1) base)
             v3     (map #(* %1 %1 %1) base)]
        (when (< i iters)
          (t/yield (yadda-iter v1 v2 v3))
          (recur
            (inc i)
            (rest v1)
            (rest v2)
            (rest v3)))))))

Testing tst.clj.core
(take 11 (yadda-lazy 4))  => (0 3 14 39 0 3 14 39 0 3 14)
(yadda-loop 4 11)         => (0 3 14 39 0 3 14 39 0 3 14)
(yadda-lazy-gen 4 11)     => (0 3 14 39 0 3 14 39 0 3 14)

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```